# Combining boost::program_options and JSON

Tags: c++, json, boost-program-options, boost-propertytree

I am currently using `boost::program_options` to parse command line and config-file arguments. However, recently I have realised I need to be able to pass my program a list of options which could be very easily summarised using e.g. JSON notation

```
algorithms: [
    {
        type: alg1,
        parameters: {},
        weight: 0.1,
    },
    {
        type: alg2,
        parameters: {},
        weight: 0.6,
    }
]
```

Where the parameter option could have a different number of arguments depending on the type. I was wondering if there is any way of giving json directly to a config-file parsed by `program_options`. The problem as I see it is that I can't make `program_options` parse a value with newlines, if it could I would be able to write something along the lines of

```
algorithms = [
    {
        type: alg1,
        parameters: {},
        weight: 0.1,
    }
]
```

parsed as a string, which I could then hand over to `boost::property_tree`. Alternatively, is there any better way of parsing these types of variable options using just `boost::program_options`? I know one option would be to simple have a separate `.json` file with the config, and give that json filename as the program option, but it would be nice to be able to have it all in one configuration file.

Comment: You may consider decision, posted in my answer to that thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44239604/c-boost-program-options-with-json-file