# C++ Boost program options with json file

Tags: c++, json, boost, boost-program-options

It is possible with boost program options library: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/program_options.html

to read json formatted file as an input file here?

Or if I have some config in json like file, I need to parse it myself, with for example: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/property_tree.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've met the same problem. Here is my implementation of JSON parser for program_options library, based on property_tree:

```
template <class charT> void parseChildren(std::string prefix, boost::property_tree::ptree& tree, boost::program_options::parsed_options& options)
{
    if (tree.size() == 0)
    {
        //cut first dot
        std::basic_string<charT> name = prefix.substr(1);
        std::basic_string<charT> value = tree.data();

        boost::program_options::basic_option<charT> opt;
        opt.string_key = name;
        opt.value.push_back(value);
        opt.unregistered = (options.description->find_nothrow(name, false) == nullptr);
        opt.position_key = -1;
        options.options.push_back(opt);
    }
    else
    {
        for (auto it = tree.begin(); it != tree.end(); ++it)
        {
            parseChildren<charT>(prefix + "." + it->first, it->second, options);
        }
    }
}

template <class charT>
void parseJsonOptions(std::basic_istream<charT>& is, boost::program_options::parsed_options& options)
{
        boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<charT>, std::basic_string<charT>> pt;
        boost::property_tree::read_json(is, pt);

        parseChildren<charT>(std::basic_string<charT>(), pt, options);
}

template <class charT>
boost::program_options::basic_parsed_options<charT> parse_json_config_file(std::basic_istream<charT>& is, const boost::program_options::options_description& desc, bool allow_unregistered = false)
{     
    // do any option check here

    boost::program_options::parsed_options result(&desc);
    parseJsonOptions(is, result);

    return boost::program_options::basic_parsed_options<charT>(result);
}
```

Use it like:

```
po::variables_map vm;
std::ifstream configFileStream(configFilePath_.generic_string());

store(parse_json_config_file(configFileStream, algorithmsDesc_), vm);
notify(vm);
```

Comment: Nice work. +1 for actually coming up with an implementation. This should potentially be featured as an example in their documentation

Answer (score 1):

> It is possible with boost program options library:
>   http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/program_options.html
>
> to read json formatted file as an input file here?

No, but you can if you write a [Parser Component](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/program_options/overview.html#idp435855552) for it

> Or if I have some config in json like file, I need to parse it myself,
>   with for example:
>   http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/property_tree.html

You can. Be sure to check the [limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44221676/does-boost-property-tree-have-methods-for-defining-rules-for-the-data-to-be-pars/44221888#44221888). Also, beware of things like "json like". Chances are that anything non-standard JSON breaks the parser, so you might want to handle it manually if it's not standard.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the provided [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45198471/13279727) `parseChildren` template to support parsing of JSON array literal:

```
template <class charT>
void parseChildren(std::string const& prefix, boost::property_tree::ptree& tree,
                   boost::program_options::parsed_options& options) {
  if (tree.empty()) {
    // remove first dot
    std::basic_string<charT> name = prefix.substr(1);
    // remove last dot if present
    if (name.back() == '.') {
      name.pop_back();
    }
    std::basic_string<charT> value = tree.data();

    boost::program_options::basic_option<charT> opt;
    opt.string_key = name;
    opt.value.push_back(value);
    opt.unregistered =
        (options.description->find_nothrow(name, false) == nullptr);
    opt.position_key = -1;
    // append value to existing option-key if it exists
    for (auto& o : options.options) {
      if (o.string_key == name) {
        o.value.push_back(value);
        return;
      }
    }
    options.options.push_back(opt);
  } else {
    for (auto it = tree.begin(); it != tree.end(); ++it) {
      parseChildren<charT>(prefix + "." + it->first, it->second, options);
    }
  }
}
```

Now parsing the following JSON should resolve in the desired CLI options output:

```
{
   "opt-1": "value-1",
   "opt-2": ["value-2-1", "value-2-2"]
}
```

when using:

```
po::options_description opts("CLI options");
  opts.add_options()                                     //
      ("opt-1", po::value<std::string>(), "opt-1 desc")  //
      ("opt-2", po::value<std::vector<std::string>>()->multitoken(), "opt-2 desc")
```